# Why is it error when I use the "at command "in the C#, but does the command work properly in the hyper terminal?

Tags: c#, sms, at-command, pdu

this is my code in c# :

```
string pdu=SubmitPdu.GetPdu("destNumber","Message","ServiceNumber");
SerialPort comport = new SerialPort();
comport.PortName = "com21";
comport.BaudRate = 921600;
comport.Parity = Parity.None;
comport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
comport.DataBits = 8;
comport.ReadBufferSize = 10000;
comport.ReadTimeout = 1000;
comport.WriteBufferSize = 10000;
comport.WriteTimeout = 1000;
comport.RtsEnable = true;
if (!comport.IsOpen)
comport.Open();
comport.DiscardInBuffer();
comport.DiscardOutBuffer();
comport.WriteLine("AT");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
comport.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=0" + (char)13);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
string s2 = "AT+CMGS=" + SubmitPdu.GetLenPdu(pdu);
comport.WriteLine(s2 + (char)13);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
comport.WriteLine(pdu + (char)26 );
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
MessageBox.Show(comport.ReadExisting());
comport.Close();
```

and result is :

> AT
>
> OK
>
> AT+CMGF=0
>
> OK
>
> AT+CMGS=15
>
> > 0691891901500011000*****************000A70178->
>
> ERROR

but when use this command in Hyper Terminal every things is okay :

> at
>
> OK
>
> at+cmgf=0
>
> OK
>
> at+cmgs=15
>
> > 069189190150001100*****************000A70178->
>
> +CMGS: 139
>
> OK

where is the bug?

thanks all

Comment: Try not to block thread and make your code asynchronous if possible. You can attach an event handler to the serial port class and read the bytes as they arrive.

Comment: So you get the error after `comport.WriteLine(pdu + (char)26 );`?  Is that correct?  `(char)26 ` is the ASCII end-of-file character.  Is that something that the receiving side can handle?  In the good-old days, that was an easy way to crash a program by signaling the end of the input stream.

Comment: Tom,I removed blocks  but the problem did not resolve.

Comment: TnTinMn,I also used this code: .WriteLine(pdu + "\x1A") too and did not make a difference. other side is a cellphone device.

Answer (score 0):

I changed .writeLine with the .write just and remove thread delay and The problem was solved .
thanks all